# How to return some data in an array from this?

Tags: php, xml, rss, preg-match

I have the following data:

```
<media:group>
    <media:content url="http://www.url.com" bitrate="450" width="320" duration="32" />
    <media:content url="http://www.url.com" bitrate="212" width="320" duration="32" />
</media:group>
```

I want to search through this and form an array like so:

```
Array (
[0] =>
 [url] => http://www.url.com,
 [bitrate] => 459,
 [width] => 320,
 [duration] => 32
[1] =>
 [url] => http://www.url.com,
 [bitrate] => 212,
 [width] => 320,
 [duration] => 32
)
```

The array above is just an example of how I want the data returned.

How can I do this? This information changes and has other things wrapped around it sometimes.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest XML Parser instead of preg_match. You make your life and the person who maintains the code's life easier.

Comment: I'm using one but all it is returning is " [media:group] => " not the contents inside it.

Comment: You should be able to access another level inside. Can you post the code where you got stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

```
<?php
$xml = '<media_group>
    <media_content url="http://www.url.com" bitrate="450" width="320" duration="32" />
    <media_content url="http://www.url.com" bitrate="212" width="320" duration="32" />
</media_group>
';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

// do an xpath query and get all item id's 
$result = $xml->xpath( '//media_content' );

$idList = array();
foreach($result as $key => $node) {
    foreach($node->attributes() as $attr=>$value) {
        $idList[$key][ (string)$attr ] = (string)$value;
    }
}

print_r($idList);
?>
```

**Note:** I have changed `media:` to `media_` because i didn't know the namespace you are using against `media`. For that, you will have to use [registerXpathNamespace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php), before you can work on the code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). Example #5 covers XML element's attributes array-like access.

Comment: This doesn't output media:group.

Comment: Here's a code, that actually outputs your XML in exactly desired format: http://pastebin.com/VwzkAm5k

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("@url\=\"(?P<url>.*?)\"\s+bitrate\=\"(?P<bitrate>.*?)\"\s+width\=\"(?P<width>.*?)\"\s+duration=\"(?P<duration>.*?)\"@msi", $sYourString, $aResult, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

or another solution:

firstly separate all the items, then go one by one, and get all the properties.

```
$aMyFullResult = array();

preg_match_all("@<media:content(?P<substring>.*?)/>@msi", $sYourString, $aResults, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($aResults as $iKey=>$aOneRow)
  preg_match_all("@\s+(\w+)\=\"(.*?)\"\s+@msi", $aOneRow['substring'], $aMyFullResult[], PREG_SET_ORDER);

print_r($aMyFullResult);
```

Comment: Hey Anton, thanks! That kind of works but it brings back 3 copies of the URLs?

Comment: Hey Latox, try to analyze results by using print_r.. with some simple steps you can get what you need. :)

Comment: I'm getting an error with the preg match inside the foreach: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array

Comment: ok, fixed some code for you :) try it now. and Please, analyse the errors, its simple to fix it.